# Compile kernel module? (Live USB)

Tags: kernel, live-usb

is it possible to compile a kernel module on a live USB stick with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? 
I have now tried for hours but all my attempts have failed.

What i've done.
Installed the linux headers.
Created a make file containing:

```
obj-m = hello.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

created a c file and added

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>         /* Needed for the macros */
static int __init hello_start(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Loading hello module...\n");
printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world\n");
return 0;
}
static void __exit hello_end(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye Mr.\n");
}
module_init(hello_start);
module_exit(hello_end);
```

When i write "make hello" i get the responds:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/EmbeddedProgramming$ make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
hello.c:1:60: fatal error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
```

When i check uname -r i get back "3.16.0-30-generic".
When i check the directory i can indeed find the module.h in that location. I got no idea why it say it cannot find the header file because it is there.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what you are trying to compile and what steps you have tried so far.

Comment: Sry, added more info now-

Comment: My copy of linux/module.h is in linux-headers. Did you first install linux-headers-generic or otherwise matching your running kernel?

Comment: Yes, i believe so.

Comment: If `cc hello.c -o hello` is the exact command being run, then it won't work. You need to use the `-I` flag to specify that that directory should be included in the search for header files. Also, note that implicit rules are at play here. See [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) page.

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I ran the wrong command in Terminal, it should be `make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules` It does work now.